# DCpromo creating child domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, active-directory

yesterday i finished working on my Windows Server 2008 R2. When i was creating a first (parent) domain controller (new domain in new forest) everything went fine. But when i wanted to install a **child domain** like from youtube.com and/or my "How to Windows Server 2008" book, i got a huge problem. Both options are installing domain controller(DC)  through dcpromo, but when **i run dcpromo i got uninstallation (removing DC) wizard**. I dont want to uninstall DC and i cant find anything to help me.
roles installed:
ADDS
DNS Server
File Server
IIS

I am a newbie in server administration so if its a kid mistake i apologize. Thanks

Comment: What is the output of the following command on the second server you want to promote as a domain controller in a new child domain:    wmic os get ProductType

Comment: I want to have a primary domain blackdeath.sk and second mail.blackdeath.sk on the same server, is it possible or i have to make Hyper-V virtual server?
cmd output is:
ProductType
2

Comment: A server can only function as a domain controller for a single domain, so if you want to have a parent domain and a child domain, you need at least two Windows server instances.  Also, you say that you want to have mail.blackdeath as a child domain...so you actually want it to be a child domain for AD separation / management reasons right?  Reason I ask is because you could easily create a DNS record for mail.blackdeath and point it at the same server if all you care about is having the mail.blackdeath name and don't need it for AD purposes.

Comment: Not to mention you probably don't want a child domain anyway.  They are only recomended in a very small number of scenarios - you probably want a second forest instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the child domain with a **new** domain controller, not with the existing domain controller.